eigenvalue of $X \mapsto A X B$
Let $\mathbb { F }$ be a field,  $A \in \mathbb { F } ^ { m \times m },  B \in \mathbb { F } ^ { n \times n }, $ and $\phi : \mathbb { F } ^ { m \times n } \rightarrow \mathbb { F } ^ { m \times n },  X \mapsto A X B. $ It is clear that if  $\lambda,  \mu$ are eigenvalues of  $A,  B$ respectively, then $\lambda \mu$ is an eigenvalue of $\phi$.  But how to prove that all eigenvalues of $\phi$ have the form?
As Gunnar Þór Magnússon commented, we need to consider the complex field?
Let $AXB=a X$, how to deduce $rank X=1$, so that $X=\alpha\beta'$?
It is easy to see $\phi$ is invertible $\Leftrightarrow |A|\cdot |B|\neq 0$.
What about the eigenvalues problem? Find the matrix of $\phi$ under standard base? But it is not the tensor product of $A,B$.

@lisyarus Yes, the product of the det...

In general it is not true that $\operatorname{rank} X=1$, e.g. consider $A=I_m$ and $B=I_n$. I guess you need a weaker statement, that one can find an eigenbasis consisting of rank-1 matrices.

I don't think the statement is true. Consider $m = n = 2$ and the real numbers, and let $B$ be rotation by $\pi/2$ and $A$ be rotation by $-\pi/2$. Then neither $A$ nor $B$ has an eigenvalue, but $X \mapsto A X B$ has at least the eigenvalue $1$ corresponding to $X = I_2$.

@GunnarÞórMagnússon If we consider the comples filed?

@xldd This might work if the field is algebraically closed. I'll have to think about it some more, which is a little difficult at the moment as school is out and I have two kids at home jumping on me.

As Gunnar mentioned in comments, this is not true in general, without assuming $\mathbb{F}$ is algebraically closed. When $\mathbb{F}$ is algebraically closed (say, $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{C}$) though, this can be proved using Jordan normal form. Indeed, $\mathbb{F}^{m \times n} = \mathbb{F}^m \otimes \mathbb{F}^n$ and then $\phi$ is simply given by $A \otimes B^t$ (verify this on $\mathbb{F}^{m \times n} \ni vw^t \mapsto v \otimes w \in \mathbb{F}^m \otimes \mathbb{F}^n$, then conclude by using linearity). Choose bases of $\mathbb{F}^m$ and $\mathbb{F}^n$ so that $A$ and $B^t$ are in Jordan normal form. Order the resulting tensor basis of $\mathbb{F}^{m \times n} = \mathbb{F}^m \otimes \mathbb{F}^n$ in lexicographic order, then one may observe that the matrix of $A \otimes B^t$ is upper triangular, with entries $\lambda\mu$ along the diagonal, where $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are diagonal entries of $A$ and $B^t$, i.e., their eigenvalues. Note that the eigenvalues of $B^t$ are the same as those of $B$. Thus, the eigenvalues of $A \otimes B^t$, or equivalently $\phi$, are exactly $\lambda\mu$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and $\mu$ is an eigenvalue of $B$.

This also shows that for non-algebraically-closed $\mathbb{F}$, the eigenvalues are ${\lambda\mu} \cap \mathbb{F}$, where $\lambda$ and $\mu$ vary over the eigenvalues in $\overline{\mathbb{F}}$
